# VB.NET Update Cookies from POST

Tags: vb.net, cookies

I've been working on this problem for the last few days and finally made some progress.. Today I managed to force the cookie through the request and the server has finally authenticated the request, however I am unable to update the cookies and transfer the authenticated cookies to the next few pages.

```
    'post form  data to page
    strUrl = "https://e926.net/user/authenticate"
    webRequest2 = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl)
    webRequest2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    webRequest2.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    webRequest2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
    webRequest2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    webRequest2.CookieContainer = cookies
    webRequest2.ContentLength = postData.Length

    requestWriter = New StreamWriter(webRequest2.GetRequestStream)
    requestWriter.Write(postData)
    requestWriter.Close()


    Dim response2 As HttpWebResponse = CType(webRequest2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim strCookies2 As String = response2.Headers("Set-Cookie")
    MsgBox(strCookies2)
    strCookies2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(strCookies2, "((e926=.*))")(1)
    strCookies2 = strCookies2.Split(";")(0)
    strCookies2 = strCookies2.Replace("e926=", "")

    cookie.Name = "e926"
    cookie.Value = strCookies2
    cookie.Domain = ".e926.net"
    cookie.HttpOnly = True
    cookie.Path = "/"
    cookies.Add(cookie)


    'recieve authenticated cookie
    webRequest2.GetResponse().Close()
```

This is the page code that actually submits the login details and deals with the actual login request, I can see in Fiddler that the 'user' cookie is sent and the 'e926/auth' cookie is updated, but I have been unable to get the updated cookies from the headers or any other method I have tried..

The page is PHP and doesn't allow 'GET' requests and of course these wouldn't help anyways since the cookies never seem to transfer properly, and the cookies have to be updated from the request.

So my question is, how do I get the updated cookies from the page in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change 'auto-redirect' from 'true' to false and it forced the cookies to be gathered from the 'auth' page as opposed to the 'home' page.